# Как задать функцию через поле формы

Tags: php, html

У меня на страничке есть форма, в нее пользователь вводит функцию по определенному шаблону.

Например, x^3+x^2+20. Из этого поля мы получаем строку с функцией.

Как ее привести к виду, удобному для вычислений? Чтобы значение x подставлялось вместо элемента строки x, и дальше уже высчитывалось значение функции в конкретной точке.

Подскажите хотя бы идею. Я понимаю, что можно просто взять и поменять x на $x, но у меня при этом получается строка "2+3", например, которая при последующих действиях и ведет себя, как строка. И даже преобразование к числу не помогает

Comment: Как крайний вариант рассматриваю написать отдельную функцию, которая сначала перемножит, потом поделить, потом сложит, потом вычтет (будет искать в строке подстроки между действиями, и рекурсивно будет все это дело считать), но, возможно, есть более простой и быстрый способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно приблизительный пример для php5.6+:

```
<?php
// формула
$str = 'x^3+x^2+20';

// проверка на синтаксис (тут, в примере, конечно просто на допустимые символы проверяется) 
if (preg_match('/[^x\d\+\-\*\/^]/', $str)) {
    die('Недопустимый символ');
}

// замена переменной и символа степени
$str = str_replace(['x', '^'], ['$x', '**'], $str);

// а дальше можно считать
$x = 5;

// не рекомендуется использовать,
// но синтаксис формулы проверили, дырок нет в безопасности у нас ;)
eval('$y = ' . $str . ';');

var_dump($y); // int(170)
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c76d0cb08f4ae7b9fa5d5c4e77b34586c58beb9

Comment: Большое спасибо!