# Как из строки "вытащить" арифметическую операцию?

Tags: php

Всем привет! Кто о чем, а я про оптимизацию: допустим есть строка "a"."+"."b", где a и b - числа. ВОПРОС: как получить результат a + b ? В лоб решать как-то не хочется, да и вместо знака "+" может стоять много чего включая sqrt(). Может есть какие-нибудь варианты? Всем спасибо.

Comment: вытащить операции `+|-|*|/|%` можно к примеру регуляркой, но что дальше? Вы же их не сможете "превратить" в действующий оператор, не прибегая к сомнительным функциям типа `eval()`. Поэтому не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: в том и вопрос, как строку превратить в оператор? если это вообще возможно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723714/186083

Answer (score 3):

> *как строку превратить в оператор?*

В PHP для таких целей есть функция [eval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php), но использовать её не рекомендуется из-за больших шансов получить уязвимость.

Для более безопасного использования функции *eval()* необходимо полностью доверять данным, которые будут переданы в неё на обработку. Например, операнды можно приводить к целочисленному типу `(int)`, а операторы `+ - etc.` можно предварительно сохранить в массив, и получать их только из массива.

*Пример решения для php>=7.1*:

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;

$operation = '+';

// Массив с допустимыми операциями
$operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/'/*и т.д.*/];

if ( ($k = array_search($operation, $operations)) !== false ) {
    $op = $operations[$k];

    $foo = function (int ...$ints) use($op) {
        [$a, $b] = $ints;
        eval("print $a $op $b;");
    };

    $foo($a, $b);
}
```

Результат предугадать не сложно: `5`

Answer (score 2):

Безопасно, но не "из коробки" решением будет перебрать все возможные операторы/функции работы с целевыми операндами `a` и `b` в вашем кейсе. Т.е. если вы знаете стек операций, то вытащить их можно именно регуляркой, как было предложено выше, а потом передать это дело и ваши операнды в специально обученный метод. Метод этот используя `switch...case` 
по типу операции будет применять ту или иную логику вычислений.

Comment: это и есть "в лоб" решить задачу